Laravel backend and WebSocket connection with React Native
How to connect WebSocket and backend in React Native ?
I have a Laravel backend and web socket  and a frontend developed in React Native. I have connected the backend using
adb reverse tcp:3000 tcp:8000
but how would I connect web socket because at some point in future I would like my React Native app to communicate to both backend and the WebSocket.
